# Как сделать так, чтобы временная задержка по таймингу прекращалась например на пятой секунде, следующей минуты, текущих суток

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как сделать так, чтобы в скрипте на Python Selenium временная задержка по таймингу прекращалась например на пятой секунде, следующей минуты, текущих суток.

Уточняю. time.sleep остановит выполнения программы на определенное число секунд и начнет продолжение через заданное число секунд. А мне нужно чтобы выполнение программы остановилось и продолжилось например на пятой секунде следующей минуты когда программа была остановлена

Comment: Поделитесь, пожалуйста, своими попытками

Comment: уточните свой вопрос, что вы имеете в виду под "временная задержка по таймингу"? если вы хотите приостановить выполнение программы - используйте `time.sleep`

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ. Но уточняю. time.sleep остановит выполнения программы на определенное число секунд и начнет продолжение через заданное число секунд. А мне нужно чтобы выполнение программы остановилось и продолжилось например на пятой секунде следующей минуты когда программа была остановлена.